# The formal definition of a Δ-set doesn't guarantee orientation, and its implications for gluing?

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff, simplicial-complex, triangulation

It seems to be that the [formal definition of a Δ-set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4846145/definition-of-a-%CE%94-set) doesn't forbid identifying different faces of a simplex, that is, face maps $d_i$ and $d_j$, $i \ne j$ may map element $a : S_n$ to a same element $b : S_{n-1}$. This means that we can have, for example, a 1-simplex $[v_0, v_0]$ that forms a loop.

That also seems to imply that the orientation isn't defined in such cases, since it is usually induced by the order on the constituent vertices.

Does this mean that there are delta complexes representable by the formal structure that don't have unique correspondence to a topological space? I'm thinking of [different gluings of the dunce cap](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3997767/different-representations-of-dunce-cap) as an example where the edges are identified; the orientation of the gluing seams seems to affect the resulting topology.

Comment: Do you know what the geometric realization is? Its simplices have a canonical orientation,which are inherited from the standard orientation of the topological $n$-simplex.

Comment: The "orientation" does not affect the represented topological space. A triangle's vertices may be labelled any which way and still be the same triangle. The choice of labelling would perhaps only affect calculations of whether or not a map preserves or reverses orientation in the sense of homological degree (or in any of the many other senses).

Comment: @VincentBoelens Thanks, I checked the Wikipedia definition of the geometric realization of the Δ-set: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_set#Definition_and_related_data

It takes a quotient space, equating simplices and their constituents (and thus, collapsing dimension and orientation and leaving only connectedness and holes), resolving the problem in a rather crude way.

Comment: @FShrike It must affect it at least when talking about the formal definition; the rule of face map composition in the definition of the Δ-set I linked in the question dictates the orientation.

Let's have edge $e_0$, consisting of vertices $v_0$ and $v_1$. Now let's have a rectangle consisting of two 2-simplices A and B in this way: 〼 (A/B, respectively), and say the left and right edges of the rectangle are both $e_0$.

Now, depending on whether you label $v_0$ and $v_1$ "straight" or "cross", the Δ-set forms either a cylinder or a Möbius strip.

Comment: @GolDDranks Indeed it is true in a sense that the 'relative' orientations matter. But the realisation of a Delta set depends only on the face data. I don't personally consider that to be orientation data, though I can see why you feel that way. I guess we are talking at cross purposes, then.

Comment: @VincentBoelens I misunderstood the definition of the geometric realization, which made misunderstood it's implications quite badly (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4849666/does-geometric-realization-of-a-%ce%94-set-collapse-connected-simplices-to-a-single-p/4849682#4849682 ) Having corrected that, now I have the tools to attack the problem at least! Thank you.

Comment: This might be relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2563941/how-does-one-orient-a-simplicial-complex

Comment: As an aside: Different $\Delta$-complexes might have homeomorphic realizations (i.e. a space can be triangulated in different ways).

Answer (score 0):

The geometric realization of 1-simplex forming a loop is: (denoting $p \in Δ^0$ as the only point in the 0-simplex)

$|S|= \{ ({e_0} \times \Delta ^1), (v_0, p)\} /_{{\sim }}$

With $\sim$ defined as:

$(e_0, d^0p)\sim (v_0, p)$

$(e_0, d^1p)\sim (v_0, p)$

The points $d^0p$ and $d^1p$ of $\Delta ^1$ would have to be the same point, which means that the 1-simplex corresponding to $e_0$ would need to be of size zero. This resolves the issue.

It seems in general that faces of the same simplex that get identified in an orientation-conflicting way, would indeed collapse to points when geometrically realized. I can see the motivation for more restricted simplical complexes because of this.